# Why developing F-35 is harder than F-22?

Tags: aircraft-design, f-22

I'm sorry if I'll be not so accurate in my description but, please, try to understand "core" of my question.

**F-22**, ignoring high cost of each aircraft, **appear to be a successful project**, developed and delivered in almost desired timeranges respecting requirements.

I sincerely don't understand **why F-35, that initially was thought to have almost same stealth performances of F-22 but at an individual cheaper cost, is running into troubles, difficulties, risk of abandoment since years**.

Develop is still ongoing and reliability and performances are still not satisfied. I thought that experience based on first stealth high perfromance fighter jet could help and speed up an aircraft like f-35 that should have lighter requirements but facts are demonstrating the opposite

Comment: They just wanted the stealth of the F-22 and the V/STOL of the AV-8 in one aircraft for a lower price, with carrier variants as well, which also needs to replace the A-10, F-18, and F-16.

Comment: Developing a plane that's good at everything is quite a bit more complex than developing a plane that's good at a couple of things. Oh, wait, that's what @fooot said... ;)

Comment: Also, the F-35 is project with 9 countries and about 20 companies involved, which makes it a political nightmare. Each country has a set of requirements from their respective military bodies (navy, air force, etc) and wants local companies to have the biggest share of the investments.

Comment: Because they wanna combine 3 aircrafts into one plane